# Switch view when animation is complete

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-4

I have an Prism application that begins with a Splash screen, then needs to change to a Start view. Here is the code for the Initialize method of the module I hoped would accomplish this:

```
  public void Initialize() {

     RegisterViewsAndServices();

     //_manager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.Content, typeof(ToolboxSplashView));

     var vmSplash = _unityContainer.Resolve<IToolboxSplashViewModel>();
     IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.Content];
     region.Add(vmSplash.View);

     var vmStart = _unityContainer.Resolve<IToolboxStartViewModel>();
     region.Deactivate(vmSplash.View);
     region.Add(vmStart.View);
  }
```

Unfortunately, when I run this I only see the Start view. If I comment out the Start view (last paragraph of the code), I see the start screen and the animation. How do I detect that the animation has completed and then change from Splash view to Start view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought, use an AggregateEvent to announce that the animation has completed and have your controlling class execute the second part of your code when it receives that aggregate event notification.

```
public void Initialize()
{
     RegisterViewsAndServices();

     IEventAggregator ea = _unityContainer.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
     ea.GetEvent<WhateverEvent>().Subscribe(NavigateNext);

     var vmSplash = _unityContainer.Resolve<IToolboxSplashViewModel>();
     IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.Content];
     region.Add(vmSplash.View);
}

public void NavigateNext(object someParam)
{
    //Navigation Code
     var vmSplash = _unityContainer.Resolve<IToolboxSplashViewModel>();
     var vmStart = _unityContainer.Resolve<IToolboxStartViewModel>();
     region.Deactivate(vmSplash.View);
     region.Add(vmStart.View);
}

//Shared code section (that both modules have access to)
public class WhateverEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<object> { }

//In your splash screen you will use the following line of code to publish
ea.GetEvent<WhateverEvent>().Publish(null);
```

Comment: OK, I can see that sortof. What triggers the aggregate event? Do I catch it in my viewModel then communicate back to the Module to finish the load process? Or can I do it all here?

Comment: It sounds like it should be in the code-behind in your view, since it is related to the animation completion. You'd raise an Aggregate Event from within the Completed event. You're controller class would have subscribed to the AggregateEvent, and then executes the necessary code. Example of Animation Completed event: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/wpf/thread/0b040d2e-155b-4abd-911d-ea7f72784fd0

Comment: You are correct about the Completed event, that worked and brought me to the event handler in the code behind. I researched and tested your aggregate event ideas, but could not get them to work. The events fired but the module was already closed when the event fired. I was able to get navigation to work, since the two views were in the same module. I've put the solution in the answer below.

Comment: Are you saying that you got it to work or you still need assistance? Yes, you can skip the aggregate event part and place your navigation code within the SplashScreen but now you're coupling the splash screen to your other module. An aggregateevent would simply announce from the splash screen that it is done. Another part of your code that is listening for that aggregate event sees the announcement and does the navigation. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/francischeung/archive/2008/06/02/decoupled-communication-with-prism-event-aggregation.aspx

Comment: Yes, I got it to work with navigation but not with event aggregation. Still learning how to do that. Thanks for the reference. I think my problem was that I subscribed to the event on the module, where as I handled the navigation in the shell view model. At the time, I didn't realize the value of a controller class. I also was concerned about the coupling, but these two views are logically coupled anyway. When the app starts they always display one after the other. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Splash and Start views are in the same module. I hooked a Completed event handler (see comment by @michael) in the code-behind of the Splash view. The module initialization now only starts the Splash view.

```
  public void Initialize() {

     RegisterViewsAndServices();

     var vmSplash = _unityContainer.Resolve<IToolboxSplashViewModel>();
     var region = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.Content];
     region.Add(vmSplash.View);
  }
```

The storyboard Xaml showing the Completed event:

```
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
     <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard Completed="StoryboardSplashCompleted">
           <DoubleAnimation
              Storyboard.TargetName="slamDunkImage" 
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
              From="0.0" To="1.0"
              Duration="0:0:2" 
              AutoReverse="True" />
        </Storyboard>
     </BeginStoryboard>
  </EventTrigger>
```

The code-behind, event handler:

```
  private void StoryboardSplashCompleted(object s, EventArgs args) {
     _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.Content, typeof(ToolboxStartView).FullName);
  }
```

The ToolboxStartView is in the same module, so no external dependencies are required.

The Shell handles the navigation request and switches out the views. The Prism.chm help file that is part of the Prism download provides a write up about View-based navigation in Chapter 8. One un-obvious issue is that the target view (ToolboxStartView in my case) must be a View-first configuration, not a ViewModel-first.